# how to save the data entered in text boxes in PHP CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, session, jquery-plugins, session-variables

in PHP  CodeIgniter application there are several pages with input text boxes and text areas.

How to implement the session save in php i.e. whnever the user closes the tab,

the entered data should remain saved until the user logs out of the application.
or is there any plugin available to achieve the same ?

my code for the same :-

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" id="myform" action="/saveform">
    Name: <input name="name" type="text" value="" /><br />
    Address: <textarea name="address"></textarea><br />
    Gender: <select name="gender">
    <option value="M">Male</option>
    <option value="F">Female</option>
    </select><br />
    Interests:<br />
    1: <input name="interests[]" type="text" value="" /><br />
    2: <input name="interests[]" type="text" value="" /><br />
    3: <input name="interests[]" type="text" value="" /><br />
    4: <input name="interests[]" type="text" value="" /><br />
    5: <input name="interests[]" type="text" value="" /><br />
    Sign up for our newsletter: <input name="signup" type="checkbox" value="1" /><br />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the form data whenever the tab or page is closed, using AJAX you can save all data in the session and then in form you can add modify like this:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" id="myform" action="/saveform">
    Name: <input name="name" type="text" value="<?php echo isset($_SESSION['user']['name']) ? $_SESSION['user']['name'] :"";?>" /><br />
    Address: <textarea name="address"><?php echo isset($_SESSION['user']['address']) ? $_SESSION['user']['address'] :"";?></textarea><br />
    Gender: <select name="gender">
    <option value="M" <?php echo $_SESSION['user']['gender']=='M' ? "selected" :"";?>>Male</option>
    <option value="F" <?php echo $_SESSION['user']['gender']=='F' ? "selected" :"";?>>Female</option>
    </select><br />
    Interests:<br />
    1: <input name="interests[]" type="text" value="<?php echo isset($_SESSION['user']['interests_0']) ? $_SESSION['user']['interests_0'] :"";?>" /><br />
    2: <input name="interests[]" type="text" value="<?php echo isset($_SESSION['user']['interests_1']) ? $_SESSION['user']['interests_1'] :"";?>" /><br />
    3: <input name="interests[]" type="text" value="<?php echo isset($_SESSION['user']['interests_2']) ? $_SESSION['user']['interests_2'] :"";?>" /><br />
    4: <input name="interests[]" type="text" value="<?php echo isset($_SESSION['user']['interests_3']) ? $_SESSION['user']['interests_3'] :"";?>" /><br />
    5: <input name="interests[]" type="text" value="<?php echo isset($_SESSION['user']['interests_4']) ? $_SESSION['user']['interests_4'] :"";?>" /><br />
    Sign up for our newsletter: <input name="signup" type="checkbox" value="1" <?php echo $_SESSION['user']['signup']=='1' ? "checked" :"";?> /><br />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: can you please elaborate "using AJAX you can save all data in the session",

Comment: @user4841621- You need to make ajax call to one of PHP file, pass all the values of form to PHP file saving it to session.